# How do I display table or similar structure in flutter with passed map json data

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I am having a `person_details.dart` file with a variable of type Map as below

```
class PersonDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map selectedData;
  ...
```

The selectedData is as below

```
{ "id":"12345", "name":"Sameer Jadhav", "score" : 90}
```

So in my flutter app when I navigate to next screen I want a dynamic display the table (or similar structure) like below

```
_________________________
 KEY     VALUES
_________________________
 id      12345
_________________________
 name    Sameer Jadhav
_________________________
 score   90
_________________________
```

Note: the JSON data fields can change to include more/ less fields
i.e.

```
{ "id":"12345", "name":"Sameer Jadhav", "score" : 90, "address" : "India"}
```

So the display should dynamically generate the table rows for the number of fields available in map.

So is there any way in flutter to achieve the same. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

*@hiashutoshsingh* thank you for your time.

**Seems like I figured out what I wanted to achieve.**

```
Container(
    child: DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(label: Text('Field')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Data')),
      ],
      rows: widget.selectedData.entries
          .map((e) => DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text(e.key.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(e.value.toString())),
              ]))
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
```

By using the DataTable you can display the `Map` into table of rows for each `key value` pair dynamically.

Comment: I have a data List of Maps .how can i show that in dataTable?

Answer (score 2):

Generate this below model and set the received value in your model and by object notation you can get all values, in case if there is any keyword you can add in it.

Set this where you are getting value and pass this through constructor.

```
PersonDetails.fromJson(data);
```

Declare your model.

```
 class PersonDetails {
          String id;
          String name;
          int score;
          String address;

          PersonDetails({this.id, this.name, this.score, this.address});

          PersonDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            id = json['id'];
            name = json['name'];
            score = json['score'];
            address = json['address'];
          }

          Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
            final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
            data['id'] = this.id;
            data['name'] = this.name;
            data['score'] = this.score;
            data['address'] = this.address;
            return data;
          }
        }
```